# redis-cli interactive mode: how to use --bigkeys

Tags: redis, redis-cli, interactive-mode

`redis-cli -h host -p port --bigkeys`

will show a list of large keys, which is very convenient.

but in my environment, I am limited to the interactive mode.

Before I can type any commands, it's already connected to redis via interactive mode. Like:

```
redis-cli -h host -p port 
> x.x.x.x@port connected!
> i can start typing here
```

Is there any way to use the --bigkeys command inside the interactive mode?

Comment: what version of redis you are using?

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava   6.0.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use --bigkeys from the CLI's interactive/REPL mode. It is only available from the command line. What you can, perhaps, do is get the database's snapshot (RDB) and load it locally. Then you'd have, hopefully, unrestricted access via your own CLI.

Alternatively, there are other tools for analyzing Redis' keyspace. One such tool that I know of is RedisInsight (https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise/redis-insight/).